# How do I install Ubuntu Core on an SD card for use on a Pandaboard?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core

I'm a beginner with Linux. I don't know much about filesystems, root directories, kernels, etcetera. I've already looked at [the official Ubuntu Core installation example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core/InstallationExample). This and other guides I have read, are either too vague for me or don't make sense to me at all.

For example, the guide says "*You will need to have the Ubuntu Core root filesystem in an accessible path.*" and instructs me to type in `$ sudo tar zxvf $path_to_root_fs`.  As if I should already know the `$path_to_root_fs`, but I don't. It also skims over the process of downloading and installing the correct kernel as if I should already know how to do this.

What are the steps for installing Ubuntu Core onto an SD card for use on a Pandaboard?

Comment: $path_to_root_fs is the full path to the Ubuntu core image you downloaded. Also, your question is lacking a lot of information: Which Ubuntu version are you using? Which version/arch of Ubuntu core you plan to use? What have you tried already/where you failed?

Answer (score 0):

Pandaboard's need an OMAP image, so those install instructions aren't what you're looking for. [Try these](http://omappedia.org/wiki/OMAP_Ubuntu_Main) (saving you a few clicks, [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OmapDesktopInstall)), as recommended by the [Pandaboard Getting Started guide](http://pandaboard.org/content/resources/getting-started). I think they are quite intelligible, but feel free to comment if you have any problems. Basically you just dd the downloaded image to the SD card. I've done this at least twice for the robotics team I lead.